# Build rows in Python Dataframe, based on values in previous column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, jupyter-notebook

My input looks like this:

```
import datetime as dt
import pandas as pd

some_money = [34,42,300,450,550]
df = pd.DataFrame({'TIME': ['2020-01', '2019-12', '2019-11', '2019-10', '2019-09'], \
                    'MONEY':some_money}) 
df
```

Producing the following:

[image]

I want to add 3 more columns, getting the `MONEY` value for the previous month, like this (color coding for illustrative purposes):

[image]

This is what I have tried:

```
prev_period_money = ["m-1", "m-2", "m-3"]
for m in prev_period_money:
    df[m] = df["MONEY"] - 10 #well, it "works", but it gives df["MONEY"]- 10...
```

The `TIME` column is sorted, so one should not care about it. (But it would be great, if someone shows the "magic", being able to get data from it.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use for pandas 0.24+ `fill_value=0` in [`Series.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html), then also are correct integers columns:

```
for x in range(1,4):
    df[f"m-{x}"] = df["MONEY"].shift(periods=-x, fill_value=0)

print (df)
      TIME  MONEY  m-1  m-2  m-3
0  2020-01     34   42  300  450
1  2019-12     42  300  450  550
2  2019-11    300  450  550    0
3  2019-10    450  550    0    0
4  2019-09    550    0    0    0
```

For pandas below 0.24 is necessary replace mising values and convert to integers:

```
for x in range(1,4):
    df[f"m-{x}"] = df["MONEY"].shift(periods=-x).fillna(0).astype(int)
```

Comment: much shorter syntax.

Comment: The `fillna(0)` per column is actually quite important, otherwise the `df = df.fillna(0)` may "pollute" the whole table.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion: Use a list comprehension with the shift function to get your three columns, concat them on columns, and concatenate it again to the original dataframe

```
(pd.concat([df,pd.concat([df.MONEY.shift(-i) for i in 
                         range(1,4)],axis=1)],
           axis=1)
  .fillna(0)
 )


    TIME    MONEY   MONEY   MONEY   MONEY
0   2020-01 34  42.0    300.0   450.0
1   2019-12 42  300.0   450.0   550.0
2   2019-11 300 450.0   550.0   0.0
3   2019-10 450 550.0   0.0 0.0
4   2019-09 550 0.0 0.0 0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

It is quite easy if you use `shift`

That would give you the desired output:

```
df["m-1"] = df["MONEY"].shift(periods=-1)
df["m-2"] = df["MONEY"].shift(periods=-2)
df["m-3"] = df["MONEY"].shift(periods=-3)
df = df.fillna(0)
```

This would work only if it's ordered. Otherwise you have to order it before.

Comment: If you knew that "shift" exists... I was expecting "Offset" as a term. :) Thanks :)

Comment: @Vityata that's true. Knowledge is power. Btw instead of three lines you can also integrate that in your for loop.

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd

columns = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov"]
some_money = [34,42,300,450,550]

df = pd.DataFrame({'TIME': ['2020-01', '2019-12', '2019-11', '2019-10', '2019-09'], 'MONEY':some_money})

prev_period_money = ["m-1", "m-2", "m-3"]
count = 1
for m in prev_period_money:
    df[m] = df['MONEY'].iloc[count:].reset_index(drop=True)
    count += 1

df = df.fillna(0)
```

Output:

```
      TIME  MONEY    m-1    m-2    m-3
0  2020-01     34   42.0  300.0  450.0
1  2019-12     42  300.0  450.0  550.0
2  2019-11    300  450.0  550.0    0.0
3  2019-10    450  550.0    0.0    0.0
4  2019-09    550    0.0    0.0    0.0
```

Comment: What is the idea of the dropping and the reseting of the index?

Comment: @Vityata `iloc` is collecting rows with raw indexes